# Separated Checkboxes not Aggregating

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox

I have a variable number (initially 8) checkboxes that all share the same `name` attribute with different values. However they are separated by many DOM elements.

For example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
         <td><input type='checkbox' name='site-1-local' value='1' checked></td>
    </tr>
</table>
.
.
.
<table>
    <tr>
         <td><input type='checkbox' name='site-1-local' value='8' checked></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Normally I would expect my php script to aggregate the common name and have something like `$_POST['site-1-local'] = array('1', ... '8')`. However when I go to assert the values server side using `print_r()` its only showing `8` (the last value in the DOM with this name) in the `$_POST['site-1-local']` array.

I'm guessing that the non-aggregation has something to do with the checkboxes not being side-by-side? However, I haven't been able to find anything on this subject.

Comment: Try `site-1-local[]` for both.

Comment: @imtheman I'm using `print_r()` on the server side so it's not an issue of how I'm printing it

Comment: How are the values passed to post? Is it a form submit or an AJAX call?

Comment: @allicarn Form submit with type `POST`

Comment: @asdf You misunderstood me. You need to use `name='site-1-local[]'` in your html. Take a look at @Berriel's link.